# Understanding Constant Multiplication Circuit for Binary Field - How to Construct Quantum Circuit from Linear Mapping

Tags: quantum-circuit, matrix-representation

I was thinking to ask this on Math Stackexchange, but maybe here would be better since I also hope the answers also explain from quantum computation context.

### Problem

So I was reading the paper ["Concrete quantum-cryptanalysis of binary elliptic curves"](https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/8741), and I got stuck in understanding how to construct **a multiplication by constant circuit for binary field**. In their [CHES presentation](https://youtu.be/LPOqI9BnTjE?t=638) and [their other paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1170.pdf), the authors describe that it is easy to construct the circuit from a matrix since multiplication by constant is just a linear mapping.

On [their other paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1170.pdf), they present this matrix as a representation of multiplication by $1 + x^2$ modulo $1 + x + x^4$:

$\Gamma =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $

which by LUP decomposition, corresponds to this circuit:

[image]

### Questions

The questions are interrelated. They are:

**1. How to construct matrix $\Gamma$?**

**2. Why the multiplication matrix is a 4x4 matrix for a 4-qubit circuit? I thought it would be 16x16 $(2^n = 16)$?**

**3. Is that particular matrix ($\Gamma$) really correct for all values?**

### My Attempts So Far

#### For Question 1

My guess is by creating two matrices, e.g., $INPUT$ and $OUTPUT$, which includes all possible inputs and the corresponding output after the constant multiplication. Then, the matrix $\Gamma$ can be obtained from $OUTPUT * INPUT^{-1}$.

I have tried from scratch: calculated all the possible 16 input and the corresponding output pairs (derived from SageMath) and make the mapping (i.e., $\left| x0,x,x^2,x^3 \right> = \left| 0010 \right> \rightarrow \left| 1110 \right>, \left| 0100 \right> \rightarrow \left| 0101 \right>$, and so on...

However, then I realized that the resulting matrix is a rectangular 16x4 matrix rather than a square matrix for each $INPUT$ and $OUTPUT$, so the inversion can not be done when I tried that on Matlab.

#### For Question 3

For each possible input, I applied $\Gamma$ to verify the output result. While 6 of them are correct, the other 10 are wrong. For example, $\left| 1011 \right> \rightarrow \left| 2231 \right>$ rather than $\left| 0011 \right> $.

I am not sure that kind of paper would contain such errors. So my bet is my approach was all wrong.

I would be very grateful if anyone could guide me on this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The matrix looks correct (assuming they used the polynomial basis). Are you familiar with Galois fields? Then I could try to formulate an answer.

Comment: Yes, I am quite familiar. Also, I am quite confident with my mapping since I calculated some by hand then verify them on SageMath. If it helps/make it more convenient to you, I could post the whole matrix of $INPUT$ and $OUTPUT$ (for Question 1), and the actual result of the multiplication to matrix $\Gamma$ which I found wrong (for Question 3)

Comment: You don't need to. Your logic seems to be correct, but you're overcomplicating things. I'll post an answer within the next hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with some background information on this problem as not all people might be familiar with it.

It is well known that finite fields for *prime* order $p$ can be constructed by taking integers modulo $p$, this is $\mathbb F_p \simeq \mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$.
From this, we can construct certain *field extensions*, namely *Galois extensions*, as follows.
Consider the univariate polynomial ring $\mathbb F_p[\theta]$ (I don't use $x$ as variable symbol to keep notation clean.)
Let $f\in\mathbb F_p[\theta]$ be an *irreducible* polynomial of degree $m$, this is $f$ cannot be written as a product of two non-constant polynomials.
Then, the quotient w.r.t. to the ideal generated by $f$, $\mathbb F_{p^m}:=\mathbb F_p[\theta]/(f)$ is a finite field with $q=p^m$ elements.
Its elements can be seen as polynomials in $\theta$ modulo $f$.

**Question 1** The first problem you're considering is to find a matrix representation of the multiplication with an element $a = 1+\theta^2$ from the finite field $\mathbb F_{2^4}=\mathbb F_{16}$ (as $1+\theta+\theta^4$ is irreducible).
More generally, the additive group of $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ has the structure of a *vector space* over $\mathbb F_p$, $\mathbb F_{p^m}^+ \simeq \mathbb F_p^m$. Choosing a *polynomial basis*, i.e. writing any element $b\in\mathbb F_{p^m}$ uniquely as
$$
 b = b_0 \theta^0 + b_1 \theta^1 + \dots + b_{m-1} \theta^{m-1}, \quad b_i \in \mathbb F_p,
$$
induces such an isomorphism by $b \mapsto (b_0,\dots,b_{m-1})\in\mathbb F_p^m$.

Since the multiplication $M_a: b \mapsto ab$ is $\mathbb F_p$-linear, $M_a$ induces a linear map on $\mathbb F_p^m$ which can be written in a basis as a $m\times m$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p$.

Now back to your example. To find the matrix representing $M_{1+\theta^2}$ in the standard polynomial basis, we have to act with $1+\theta^2$ on all four basis elements, i.e. on $\theta^0,\dots,\theta^3$. This yields:
$$
 1 \mapsto 1+\theta^2, \quad \theta \mapsto \theta + \theta^3, \\ \theta^2 \mapsto \theta^2 + \theta^4 = 1 + \theta + \theta^2, \quad \theta^3 \mapsto \theta(\theta^2+\theta^4) = \theta+\theta^2+\theta^3.
$$
We can now extract the expansion coefficients from the images and write them as columns of the matrix representation
$$
 M_{1+\theta^2} \simeq \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} =\Gamma.
$$
This should answer **Question 3** (btw in your example, you have to take the result modulo 2, since we're in $\mathbb F_2$!).

**Question 2** That $M_a$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix should be clear by now. How is this now related to quantum circuits? We can label the computational basis of a $n$-qubit system by vectors $x\in\mathbb F_2^n$, namely we set
$$
| x \rangle := | x_1 \rangle \otimes \dots \otimes |x_n\rangle.
$$
Matrices $M\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb F_2)$ act naturally on this basis by $| x \rangle \mapsto | Mx\rangle$, i.e. they only permute the computational basis. As such, they clearly define a unitary $U_M$. Note that the unitary has dimension $2^n \times 2^n$ and complex (here: real) entries but $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with binary entries.

**Remark**: It is a well-known fact that $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb F_2)$, i.e. the reversible linear Boolean circuits, is generated by $CNOT$ gates with representation
$$
 CNOT_{12} \simeq \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad CNOT_{21} \simeq \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This basically follows from the PLU decomposition together with rewritting permutations as CNOT circuits.

Comment: It did not come to my mind _at all_ to modulo the result! 
And thanks for stressing about the _basis_, that clears up much of my confusion.
One question, is the term LUP and PLU decomposition interchangeable?

Comment: @prairie99 If I'm not mistaken, LUP and PLU are basically interchangeable: LUP states that $PA = LU$ and PLU that $A = P' LU$. Although the permutations might not be unique, we can take $P' = P^{-1}$ such that one decomposition follows from the other.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to construct the swap gates given the corresponding $n$ x $n$ permutation gate? If yes, I will make a new question for this. (Note: I already understand how to make the corresponding CNOT from the L and U matrix, but my swap implementation has not given completely correct result).

Comment: @prairie99 the task you want to solve is to write a permutation $\pi$ as a product of transpositions (since this is what SWAP gates are!). This is always possible, but non-unique. I remember some paper which proposes an algorithm for this in the context of circuit synthesis, but I cannot find it right now ... Perhaps, you should open a new question for this, I'll try to find it :)

Comment: [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21856/how-to-construct-swap-gates-from-permutation-matrix) is my question, I'd be happy to have more answers :) thank you!